# Pessimistic locking in grails 3+ lock()

Tags: hibernate, grails, locking, grails-orm, pessimistic-locking

```
    def check(){
        println"start first"
        Domain1 domain1=Domain1.get(1);
        domain1.lock();
        println "locking started"
        sleep(20*60)
        println "save first"
        domain1.name="hari ram"
        domain1.save();
        println "save first completed"

    }
    def check2(){
        try {
            println"start second"
            Domain1 domain1=Domain1.get(1);
            println"save second"
            domain1.name="hari ram -------------------++++++++"
            domain1.save(flush:true,failOnError:true);
            println "save second completed"
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.each{
                println "error ${ex}"
            }
        }
    }
```

My log from above code is :

```
start first
locking started
start second
save second
save second completed
save first
save first completed
```

And the database gets updated too. Why is lock() not working? isn't it that after lock() other instance is not able to update? Or is something else? or am i missing something?

Comment: missing a lot start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301395/grails-what-does-saveflushflush-inserttrue-do-differently-from-saveflus

Comment: @vahid  have tried flushing as well

Comment: I think there is a lot you are not understanding. I think the lock method is designed to work within a trail of transactions - something calls something locks it does something returns checks lock and so on it is all part of the same transaction but obviously more complex than you have imagined above. The fact you are doing something 1 place then calling another `transactional` - hard to know since the above looks like all from a controller call and this time issuing a flush:true -  telling it that it must do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling `check` and `check2` with the same session?  The `lock()` method selects the row for update (at the DB level), but if you come in in the same session and attempt to get the same object, you should be getting it from the hibernate session rather than going to the database and having to wait on the row to be released.

I'm not positive this is your issue, but it looks like your code is right (though you'd be better using `Domain.lock(1)` to get and lock it at the same time in this example, there's nothing wrong with making the two calls separately).

Comment: well i called check1 from one browser and and check2 from other browser, i only need to lock the row .